# Clearing a table - JQuery

Tags: jquery

Not quite sure what's going sideways here.

The below function should clear all the rows and then create new rows, but while it does clear on-screen for a moment, it keeps the previous rows and appends to them.

Is this because of the use of appendTo? Why should it matter when it's occurring after the rows have been cleared?

Is there another / better way to clear a table and write an array?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function buildrow(){
        $( "#oatable tbody tr" ).each( function(){
            this.parentNode.removeChild( this ); 
              });

        $('input:checkbox:checked').each(function() { 
                var idtofind = ($(this).attr('id'));
                //alert(idtofind);
                //alert(idtofind);          
                //Hide Content (this is sloppy but easy to customize..)
                //$(wrapper).hide();
                //('This is the first ' + idtofind);    
                //Get XML Data
                $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "xml/OA.xml",
                dataType: "xml",
                success: function(xml) {
                    var tablediv = $('div#table');
                    var xmlArr = [];
                    $(xml).find('OAData').each(function(){
                                                if($(this).attr('OAval')===idtofind) {
                            //alert('This is the next ' + idtofind);
                        var xml_OAval           = $(this).attr('OAval');
                        var xml_OAid            = $(this).find('OAid').text();
                        var xml_BAC_Level_1         = $(this).find('BAC_Level_1').text();
                        var xml_Basel_Level_1       = $(this).find('Basel_Level_1').text();
                        var xml_Basel_Level_2       = $(this).find('Basel_Level_2').text();
                        var xml_Risk_Category_Level_3   = $(this).find('Risk_Category_Level_3').text();
                        var xml_GTO_Library_Ref_ID  = $(this).find('GTO_Library_Ref_ID').text();
                        var xml_Ent_Lib_Ref_ID      = $(this).find('Ent_Lib_Ref_ID').text();
                        var xml_Name            = $(this).find('Name').text();
                        var xml_Description     = $(this).find('Description').text();
                        var xml_Potential_Risk_Event    = $(this).find('Potential_Risk_Event').text();
                        var xml_Cause           = $(this).find('Cause').text();
                        var xml_GTO_Library     = $(this).find('GTO_Library').text();
                        var xml_Comments        = $(this).find('Comments').text();
                        // Add matched items to an array
                        xmlArr += '<tr><td>';
                        xmlArr += xml_OAid;
                        xmlArr += '</td><td>';
                        xmlArr += xml_BAC_Level_1;
                        xmlArr += '</td><td>';
                        xmlArr += xml_Basel_Level_1;
                        xmlArr += '</td><td>';
                        xmlArr += xml_Basel_Level_2;
                        xmlArr += '</td><td>';
                        xmlArr += xml_Risk_Category_Level_3;
                        xmlArr += '</td><td>';
                        xmlArr += xml_GTO_Library_Ref_ID;
                        xmlArr += '</td><td>';
                        xmlArr += xml_Ent_Lib_Ref_ID;
                        xmlArr += '</td><td>';
                        xmlArr += xml_Name;
                        xmlArr += '</td><td>';
                        xmlArr += xml_Description;
                        xmlArr += '</td><td>';
                        xmlArr += xml_Potential_Risk_Event;
                        xmlArr += '</td><td>';
                        xmlArr += xml_Cause;
                        xmlArr += '</td><td>';
                        xmlArr += xml_GTO_Library;
                        xmlArr += '</td><td>';
                        xmlArr += xml_Comments;
                        xmlArr += '</td></tr>';

                        //alert(xmlArr);
                        }
                      }); // end each loop

                  //Append array to table (this way is much faster than doing this individually for each item)
                  //alert(xmlArr)
          $(xmlArr).appendTo("tbody#oa");
        } // end post AJAX call operaitons
        }); // end AJAX
            }

    );
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: Can you reproduce your problem with a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) demo?

Comment: Since almost all jquery functions work against all the elements in the matched set you almost never want to use $.each against a matched set (it is far more useful against arrays and objects if you're doing functional programming) - just a rule of thumb for checking when you might be going off the rails.

Comment: @DavidThomas Not really clear on how to use the XML source files inside of JS Fiddle

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To remove all the rows from a `table` `tbody` use this code.

```
$("#oatable tbody tr").remove();
```

`.remove()` reference: http://api.jquery.com/remove/

In your `ajax` success handler you have defined `xmlArr` as an array and you are concatenating string to it which is not corerct. Use the `push` method to add string to it.

```
success: function(xml) {
   var tablediv = $('div#table');
   var xmlArr = [];
   ....
   ....
   //xmlArr += '<tr><td>';
   //use push method
   xmlArr.push('<tr><td>');
   ....
   ....                    
   ....
   xmlArr.push('</td></tr>');
   ....
   ....



   //Finally use xmlArr.join('') to get the combined string
   $(xmlArr.join('')).appendTo("tbody#oa");

}
```

Comment: .remove() didn't work, the data was still appended to the previous data as if it was not cleared.

Comment: that line of code would remove the entire row, not clear the content inside the row. `.remove();` removes the element specified.

Comment: I thought that is what OP is looking for. The OP is creating new rows with 'tr/td' and not just setting the `html` for td's.

Comment: Shankar is right. With this code in the onChange of the select box you can completely clear all the rows and columns and specify a new table: $("#oatable #oa tr").remove();

Comment: Ah, I guess I misunderstood the question. I thought he wanted to clear the data from the rows. My fault.

Answer (score 2):

The above answer is in the right direction however you are asking whether to **clear** the data from a table. The best way, from my point of view would be to do the following:

```
$("#oatable tbody tr td").html("");
```

This will clear all the data from each  element in your table.

Best Regards and good luck,

Comment: That is just clearing the first row - I'm going to try to see if I can get this in jsfiddle

Comment: Strange. I've done a small test which has shown me it does clear all the rows using $("table td").html("");

Comment: Source http://mdihosting.com/5/Projects/VRACC/index3.html - I'm working w/ this now, so it's being continuously updated but if you look at it in firebug you should see what it returns.

Comment: if you're trying to clear ALL the tds in a table you have to be less specific, so just `$("td").html("");` should do it.

Comment: Ok, I've learned something NEW - if the Category selection remains the same, it does clear and over-write. If the Category selection CHANGES it appends. I have no idea why this is, but it's def. showing that there is a difference with a different category.

Comment: @JeremyMiller Could it be that the array itself isn't clearing?

Comment: ChadM, This code: $("#oatable #oa tr").remove(); should be placed within the onChange of the select field. I don't want credits for this as Shankar actually found the right solution immediately :)

Answer (score 0):

try replace this

```
 $( "#oatable tbody tr" ).each( function(){ 
        this.parentNode.removeChild( this );  
          }); 

 $(xmlArr).appendTo("tbody#oa")
```

For this

```
$( "#oatable tbody" ).html("");

$( "tbody#oa" ).html($(xmlArr));
```

Comment: For some reason the .html selector hasn't worked at all for me. I've just done this replace as you suggested and the table remains blank / no errors / as if nothing executed

Comment: Acording to this pag http://api.jquery.com/text/ `.html();` doesn't work with xml.  `.text()` can be used with both xml and html.

Comment: Found the problem - Idiot OP (me) failed to empty the div containing the checkboxes, so each time a new category was selected more checkboxes were being written to the div. The code here provided by you guys worked, problem was it was running against cascades of checkboxes that shouldn't have been created.

Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
 if tbody is there :
  $("#tablename tbody tr").remove();
 else:
  $("#tablename tr").remove();
```